# issue in sqlite app in SQLiteOpenHelper class

Tags: android, sqlite

i am learning sqlite from slidenerd. Following all as mention in tutorials but getting issue.
Constructor is working properly but oncreate is not working.

Openhelper class code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

public class Kamisqlhelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME="kamidatabase";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME="kamitable";
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION=1; 
    private static final String id="_id";
    private static final String names="Name";
    private static final String contact="PhoneNo";
    private static final String CREATE_TABlE = "create table "+TABLE_NAME+"("+id+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+names+" varchar(255), "+contact+" integer);"; 
    private static final String droptable= "drop table "+TABLE_NAME+" if exists";
    private Context context;

    public Kamisqlhelper(Context context){
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.context=context;
        toastmessage.showtoast(context, "constructor called");

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(CREATE_TABlE);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            toastmessage.showtoast(context, ""+e);
            toastmessage.showtoast(context, "oncreate called");
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
            db.execSQL(droptable);
            onCreate(db);
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            toastmessage.showtoast(context, ""+e);
            toastmessage.showtoast(context, "onupgradecalled");
        }

    }

}
```

Main activity code

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.view.Menu;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    Kamisqlhelper kamihelper;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    kamihelper = new Kamisqlhelper(this);
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = kamihelper.getWritableDatabase();
}


}
```

please also suggest better up to date tutorial on sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onCreate` is called when the database is created for the first time, that means  when you first use the SQLiteOpenHelper，it will be called， otherwise，it never be called [SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html#onCreate)

Comment: but it is not being called even at first time

Comment: your code `toastmessage.showtoast(context, "oncreate called");`  is in  catch exception block, move it into the try block?